# Android Room Many to many relation with associateBy and Junction not compiling

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-room

I tried same code as of given in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many exactly with room 2.2.0.

```
@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val playlistName: String
)

@Entity
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey val songId: Long,
    val songName: String,
    val artist: String
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["playlistId", "songId"])
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    val playlistId: Long,
    val songId: Long
)

data class PlaylistWithSongs(
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "playlistId",
        entityColumn = "songId",
        associateBy = Junction(PlaylistSongCrossRef::class, parentColumn = "playlistId", entityColumn = "songId")
    )
    val songs: List<Song>
)
```

I have more complex data but when i tried same code from link it shows

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.List<com.skybase.compose_tut.PlaylistWithSongs>).
```

I am wondering why this sample code not working?

Comment: You need to add the method(s) in the @Dao annotated interface/abstract class as that is where the issue has been found (i.e. it cannot handle the RETURN type)

Answer (score 0):

You issue will be with one of the functions (methods in java) in the `@Dao` annotated interface (or abstract class). The code provided (Song, Playlist, PlaylistSongCrossref and the POJO PLaylistsWithSongs) are all OK.

In the `@Dao` annotated interface you want something like:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM playlist")
fun getAllPlayListsWithSongs(): List<PlaylistWithSongs>
```

The **return type** being `List<PlaylistWithSongs>`

**Demo**

With a project with your code and the following extra code for the database:-

```
@Database(entities = [Song::class,Playlist::class,PlaylistSongCrossRef::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for convenience/brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(song: Song): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(playlist: Playlist): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(playlistSongCrossRef: PlaylistSongCrossRef): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM playlist")
    fun getAllPlayListsWithSongs(): List<PlaylistWithSongs>
}
```

and then the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dbInstance: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dbInstance = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = dbInstance.getAllDAOs()

        var song1Id = dao.insert(Song(songId=1, songName = "Song1", artist = "Artist1"))
        var song2Id = dao.insert(Song(songId=2, songName = "Song2", artist = "Artist1"))
        var song3Id = dao.insert(Song(songId=3, songName = "Song3", artist = "Artist2"))

        var pl1id = dao.insert(Playlist(playlistId = 100, playlistName = "Playlist 1"))
        var pl2id = dao.insert(Playlist(playlistId = 101, playlistName = "Playlist 2"))
        var pl3id = dao.insert(Playlist(playlistId = 102, playlistName = "Playlist 3"))

        dao.insert(PlaylistSongCrossRef(pl1id,song1Id))
        dao.insert(PlaylistSongCrossRef(pl1id,song2Id))
        dao.insert(PlaylistSongCrossRef(pl1id,song3Id))

        dao.insert(PlaylistSongCrossRef(pl2id,song2Id))

        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (pws in dao.getAllPlayListsWithSongs()) {
            sb.clear()
            for (s in pws.songs) {
                sb.append("\n\tSong ID is ${s.songId} Name is ${s.songName} Artist is ${s.artist}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","PLaylist ID is ${pws.playlist.playlistId} Name is ${pws.playlist.playlistName} it has ${pws.songs.size} songs: They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

Then it compiles (using Room 2.2.0 libraries) fine and when run results in the expected:-

```
D/DBINFO: PLaylist ID is 100 Name is Playlist 1 it has 3 songs: They are:-
        Song ID is 1 Name is Song1 Artist is Artist1
        Song ID is 2 Name is Song2 Artist is Artist1
        Song ID is 3 Name is Song3 Artist is Artist2
D/DBINFO: PLaylist ID is 101 Name is Playlist 2 it has 1 songs: They are:-
        Song ID is 2 Name is Song2 Artist is Artist1
D/DBINFO: PLaylist ID is 102 Name is Playlist 3 it has 0 songs: They are:-
```

Comment: Yes, I do have dao to get playlist with songs

atDao
interface PlaylistDao{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Playlist")
    fun getPlaylistsWithSongs(): List<PlaylistWithSongs>
}

I already did everything you suggested in your answer but still same error is showing.
Here are some more info 
Using Mac M1
Android Studio Artic Fox Patch 4
min 21 target 31
kotlin compiler 1.5.21